# Input = list of tuples, output = list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

Kindly help me in getting the code using python 3.7 for below scenario:
I have a list of tuples as input like:
boxes = [(10,40,50,20),(15,40,50,20)]
I want to create a list of dictionaries so that my output comes in below format:

```
[
 {
  "top":10,
  "right":40,
  "bottom":50,
  "left":20
 },
 {
  "top":15,
  "right":40,
  "bottom":50,
  "left":20
 }
 ]
```

I tried json.dumps() but not getting in expected format

Answer (score 3):

```
boxes = [(10,40,50,20),(15,40,50,20)]
dicts = []

for b in boxes:
    top, right, bottom, left = b
    dicts.append({'top': top, 'right': right, 'bottom': bottom, 'left': left})

print(dicts)
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily done with a list comprehension.

In the function below, each tuple of values in the input list is zipped together with the list of keys to create the required key-value pairs, which are in turn used to initialize a dictionary object.

```
keys = ["top", "right", "bottom", "left"]

def convert(list_of_tuples):
    return [dict(zip(keys, vals)) for vals in list_of_tuples]
```

Comment: I guess this will be the fastest method of all- nice.

Comment: Loved the approach this looks better

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to mind is:

```
boxes = [(10,40,50,20),(15,40,50,20)]
new_boxes = []
for box in boxes:
    new_boxes.append({'top': box[0],
                      'right': box[1],
                      'bottom': box[2],
                      'left': box[3]})
print(new_boxes)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop over each tuple and create a dictionary using that.

```
>>> t =  [(10,40,50,20),(15,40,50,20)]
>>> d =  []
>>> for i in t: 
...   d.append({'top': i[0], 'right': i[1], 'bottom': i[2], 'left': i[3]})
... 
>>> d
[{'top': 10, 'right': 40, 'bottom': 50, 'left': 20}, {'top': 15, 'right': 40, 'bottom': 50, 'left': 20}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the list can create dicts as follows

```
final = []
for t in m_tuple_list:
  final.append({ 'top': t[0], 'bottom': t[1], 'left': t[2], 'right': t[3] })

print (final)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` to apply the same operation on elements of a list.

```
def convert(x):
    return {
  "top":x[0],
  "right":x[1],
  "bottom":x[2],
  "left":x[3]
 }

inputs = [(10,40,50,20),(15,40,50,20)]
list_dic = list(map(convert, inputs))
print(list_dic)
# output
#[{'top': 10, 'right': 40, 'bottom': 50, 'left': 20},
#{'top': 15, 'right': 40, 'bottom': 50, 'left': 20}]
```